# Ancient English 101

Tags: translation, history

I'm trying to make alerting messages on my website feel old-fashioned. Is there any straightforward approach to translate modern English into ancient English? I can't tell which exact stage of English is what I want, because the [history of English language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_English) is an overwhelming reading work for me.

I'll try to explain my question by giving examples. The following sentence is not what I want, because I don't think an average English native speaker can understand it with no effort.

> - Her swutelað seo gecwydrædnes ðe

<sub>source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English)</sub>

I expect those which seem old, but is still *comprehensible* by common English speakers:

> - Thou shalt regret thine action!
> - I thank thee for thy contribution.
> - In return to thy service, I grant thee the gift of Immortality!

<sub>source: A game named [Nethack](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Aligned_priest)</sub>

I think a word-by-word lookup table should be enough to do this, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know why your software would ever need to say "Here is made manifest the covenant to you" in Old English (a.k.a. Anglo-Saxon) because nobody but an OE geek like me would get it. But a word-for-word translation into [Wardour Street English](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-war1.htm), i.e., faux Early Modern English that is intended to be reminiscent of Shakespeare (such as your last three examples illustrate) would be of little use either unless you were able to follow the grammatical rules well enough. Better would be a phrase lookup table.

Comment: If you have sufficient patience, you could use the u.mich ME corpus to find something or other: http://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/med/ (A hint: for verisimilitude, use lots of words with ash (æ), thorn (þ, Þ) or (ð, Ð), and lower or upper-case yogh (Ȝ ȝ).)